# What's the text command for this symbol?

Tags: symbols

Does anyone know the name of the symbol to the left ? I saw it as a way of numbering sections inside the book Basic Mathematics by Serge Lang.

[image]

Comment: For future reference, [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) can provide names of symbols that you draw by hand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wikipedia calls it [Section sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_sign).  `\S` does it

```
\documentclass[11]{article}
\begin{document}
\S
\end{document}
```

[image: section character]

Comment: Or simply `§` directly from the keyboard since nowadays, the default input encoding is `utf8`.

Comment: `\textsection` should work also

Answer (score 4):

It is possibile, as alternative, to use `\textsection` in text-mode (as by comment of @Fab2) and `\mathsection` in math-mode.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
\textbf{\textsection 5} or $\bm{\mathsection 5}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A symbol near and dear to my heart...https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/25858/steven-b-segletes?tab=profile

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Dear and very kind Steven: I have not forgotten you :-)